# Theming Activity- Changing the color of StatusBar

Tags: android, android-activity, styles

My application have activities and am not using support library. But I would like to change the **colorPrimaryDark** of a class which extends **Activity**(not AppCompat).

I have used below code in my **style.xml** and changed actionBar color

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
```

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Now, my activity's actionBar look like below

[image: this]

But I want it to look something like this,

[image: this]

Someone's help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution after trying many things.
Use any of **Material** Theme as parent with **android:colorPrimaryDark** as below

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
     <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
     <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Top bar is known as status bar so adding the below code to your theme should work.

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/your_color</item>
```

Comment: @ Vivek Mishra, what is the parent for using statusBarColor? I tried what you have suggested but no luck end up with same as before.

Comment: In Manifest, I used <application android:theme="@style/MyTheme"/>

Comment: your parent for status bar should be MyTheme

Comment: Used as below, but still not working <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

Comment: Can someone help?

Comment: try changing your my action bar parent.